# T-SQL function to return more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a T-SQL function to return all the associated columns of the statistics attribute
I am passing the stats_id and object_id of sys.stats system table.
I need all the columns separated by ',' but my function returns just the first column.Pls help
I am working on Sql server 2005

```
create FUNCTION fGetstatscols (
    @objectid INT,
    @stats_id  INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_IncludedCol NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE collist CURSOR
    ( select (name) from sys.columns where Object_id =@objectid 
        and column_id in (select column_id from  sys.stats_columns where object_id=@objectid 
        and stats_id=@stats_id))   
    OPEN collist
    FETCH NEXT FROM collist INTO @V_IncludedCol
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    begin 
        Select @V_IncludedCol = COALESCE(@V_IncludedCol + ',', '') 
    END
    close collist
    deallocate collist
    RETURN @V_IncludedCol
END
```

Comment: So you do want only ONE value returned, you just want it to have different content? Besides, why do you want to return a string with the columns instead of the column names themselves? Who is going to use the string? If you call this from code, it's far easier to do string manipulation in code

Comment: No I need all the columns separated by comma.I am using those columns In another script(Create statistics) from where I am calling the function .

Comment: SQL Server has two data structures that are intended to be used yo contain *multiple* pieces of data. These are a) the table, and b) XML. A string containing comma separated values isn't on this list. Yes, you can create one. But you really shouldn't. It's not a natural representation for such data. How is the output of this function consumed?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using cursor in this and most other cases.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fGetstatscols (
    @objectid INT,
    @stats_id  INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_IncludedCol NVARCHAR(200) = ''
    SELECT @V_IncludedCol += ','+name 
    FROM sys.columns c 
    WHERE Object_id =@objectid 
        and exists (SELECT 1 from  sys.stats_columns 
                    WHERE object_id=@objectid 
                     and stats_id=@stats_id
                     and c.column_id=column_id)
    RETURN stuff(@V_IncludedCol, 1,1, '')
END
```

You should be aware, that it is possible to let the function return a table with the results as well.

Comment: thanks  t-clausen.dk for your solution..But ur function just returns the last column...There are more than 5 columns and it fetches just the last column

Comment: @user2815115 I suspect that will be because of your restriction: and stats_id=@stats_id. Are you sure that is a restriction you need ? It will return more columns if you remove that part

Answer (score 0):

Every time the WHILE loops the `@V_IncludedCol` variable gets filled with the new value, that why you get only one value

```
create FUNCTION fGetstatscols (
    @objectid INT,
    @stats_id  INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_IncludedCol NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @retval NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE collist CURSOR
    ( select (name) from sys.columns where Object_id =@objectid 
        and column_id in (select column_id from  sys.stats_columns where object_id=@objectid 
        and stats_id=@stats_id))   
    OPEN collist
    FETCH NEXT FROM collist INTO @V_IncludedCol
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    begin 
        if @retval is null 
            select @retval = @V_IncludedCol
        else 
            Select @retval = retval + ',' + @V_IncludedCol
    END
    close collist
    deallocate collist
    RETURN @retval
END
```

But you are better using **t-clausen.dk** solution, that avoids using a cursor

Comment: thx all for your help..I got the required output by using the stuff and FOR XML PATH ........thx again for all ur valuable suggessions